# To change the default printer name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to change the default printer name, using JavaScript code.
The below code open the print dialog successfully, but I want to set
our own printer name. The client side all the printer name have saved it in database.
Can it be changed  statically or dynamically?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
      <html> 
     <head>  
      <script>
       function printpage()
        {   
         window.print(); 
        } 
      </script> 
     </head> 
     <body> 
     <input type="button" value="Print this page" onclick="printpage()" /> 
    </body> 
  </html>
```

Comment: I can smell an intranet app here. In that case you can do this with IE, but not with other browsers. More info?

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

For starters, how would you even know the name of the printer the user will have?

Comment: The printer is outside the realm of javascript. +1

Comment: i have created the applet for saving all the client site printer name in database table

Comment: What if user can enter his printers names manually? What if we want to print two types of documents using different printers? The web technology becomes more and more not only for a web serfing but a tool to create business apps.